# Problems trying to get USB Debugging working on Windows 7 (Android)

Tags: android, windows, debugging, usb

I am using Windows 7 64bit and I am trying to get my computer to detect my HTC Desire, but it's not picking it up. I have everything available installed through the Android Updater and I have got my phone running through Ubuntu, so it is definitely a problem with Windows. Does anyone know what's wrong or how to get it working or both?

- I am using Windows 7 64 bit
- I have a HTC Desire running Stock 2.2 (Froyo) that works with USB Debugging on my Ubuntu machine
- Windows does detect that my phone is plugged in. It shows as a mass storage device.
- I have all the available things installed via the Android Updater.

Comment: One thing to check - Ignoring debugging for the moment, can Win7 see your phone at all? do you get prompted by the device to mount as a USB Storage device when plugged in. If so, does Win 7 see that?

Comment: Yes. It shows as a Disk Drive (which is my default setting). It's just the SDK that won't pick it up. Thanks. Gonna edit the OP and add that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I went through a huge hassle with this last night (took me 4-6 hours), but finally got it working. Based off of what you have said you already accomplished, complete these steps:

1. Reboot your computer (really, it couldn't hurt and who knows what residuals are chilling there that can screw this all up).
2. Connect your phone
3. In Device Manager, right-click any unknown devices related to your phone and update drivers. Manually point to the usb_drivers\ directory from your Android SDK.
4. At this point you should only have one undetected device (ADB), Windows will not be able to find drivers for it.
5. Download [USBDeview](http://download.cnet.com/USBDeview/3000-2094_4-10614190.html), run as Administrator (requires right-click) and uninstall your phone and any ADB drivers it lists (your phone should still be connected).
6. Disconnect your phone.
7. Download [HTCSync](http://www.htc.com/www/SupportViewNews.aspx?dl_id=1062&news_id=806) and install it.
8. Connect your phone, Windows should now attempt to install drivers and do so no problem.
9. Open a command window and type `adb devices` to confirm everything is running correctly (that is, if you placed the AndroidSDK's tools directory in your PATH variable).

Comment: HTCSync. Awesome. It completely, easily and quickly solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you already checked out the article on [USB drivers for Windows](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)? I'm not quite sure if you are supposed to install the drivers via the Android Updater.

Comment: I have done. Yes thanks. I was amazed at how simple it is to do on Windows :) Too bad I can't get it working :(

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem on Windows 7 x64 and uninstalling in device manager then selecting manual install gave an error (something like: ensure driver is 64-bit compatible). Resolved as follows:

1. Connect phone
2. Run [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) as Administrator
3. Sort by Serial Number
4. Select all devices with Serial Number starting HT
5. Uninstall selected devices
6. Disconnect/reconnect phone
7. Windows will try, and fail, to install device, ignore that and...
8. Install driver via Device Manager:

   1. Open Device Manager (**Start**->**My Computer**, right click->**Manage**->**Device Manager**)
   2. Under Other, you should see a device with a yellow warning called **ADB** or **Android Phone**; right click -> **Update driver software...**
   3. Click **Browse my computer for driver software**
   4. Click **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer**
   5. Select **Show all devices**, click **Next**
   6. Click **Have disk...**
   7. Browse to android sdk install directory and find the usb_driver directory (mine is in extras\google)
   8. Select **android_winusb.inf** and click **OK**
   9. Select **Android Composite ADB Interface** and click **Next**
   10. When the Update Driver Warning appears click **Yes**

(Props to craigcrawford1988 on http://android.modaco.com/topic/309154-adb-device-driver-installation-failed-on-window-7-x64/)

Comment: Note that (8) only worked for me after uninstalling devices with USBDeview, before that it just gave the error I described at the start of the post

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working in XP by editing the drivers .inf file.  It seems the Desire is not listed in it.

Edit android_winusb.inf in the adt\android-sdk-windows\usb_driver folder.

I added the following lines to the relevant NTx86 or NTamd64 section.

;HTC Desire
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87&REV_0100&MI_01

This worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very helpful link I followed for setting up my HTC Droid Incredible.

[USB Drivers Setup Android Windows 7](http://www.flexjunk.com/2010/05/01/installing-htc-incredible-android-sd-drivers/)

If you do not modify android_winusb.inf the USB debugging won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of not being able to launch the Android app from Eclipse on real phone and not in AVD. Once I installed HTC Sync, it did the magic and I was able to use real phone.

Cheers,

Madhu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my windows 7.
Here is how i fixed that:

1. Goto Device Manager
2. If your device is already detected as MTP device
   **right click on it > Update > Browse > Let me pick**
3. Change **MTP device** to **USB Composite** from compatible hardware list, then click **Next**.
4. If you don't see any compatible hardware list

- Click **Have Disk > (browse android sdk) > Install**