# How to solve Unity "No compatible android device found"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb

I have a Unity app that I've been developing and about to release, I was trying to resolve one last bug and I uninstalled and reinstalled Unity as a last ditch effort. When I got back in and loaded my app, Unity can no longer find my device.

If I go to "Player settings" my phone is listed under "Run Device". If I go into ADB and do "adb devices -l" it shows the Pixel 3. Then in my phone I have it set to USB Debugging and I do a build and get the typical "No compatible Android device found" error. I'm completely at a loss.

Any other ideas?

*(Windows 10, Unity3D 2018.2.15f1, Most current build of Android Studio with Android 8.0, 8.1 and 9.0 sdks, Devices are Pixel XL and Pixel 3 XL).*

Comment: I think Yugo should include screenshot of what you have tried so far and the result like my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36825304/3785314) post. Type `adb devices` not `adb devices -l`

Comment: I'm not sure what happened or what got changed, but I stashed my current build and reverted the project. The phone is recognized just fine now but now I'm dealing with a Java heap issue. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your can create new question with your new issue and provide enough info on the error to help you.

Comment: Agreed I can ask the question elsewhere. I will if i need help with that. I was just updating the comments so others knew what happened. I understand that this platform needs questions to be individual.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the driver for Android device on your computer.
2. Enable DEBUGGING in your Android device.

For Unity to be able to detect your Android device, it must be recognizable by the ADB program.

Answer (score 1):

May be due to missing of ADB.
install the ADB

Answer (score 1):

So in the end, what worked for me, I went in and uninstalled Java entirely from my computer and then I reinstalled the latest version.

This worked. I know it's less than ideal but It was the only thing.

I appreciate the help but my ADB was working just fine, I could find my device and Unity could see my device until I tried to build and then it would be lost. Also, yes, debugging was on in my android.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to revoke all authorizations on your phone settings and then plug it back in again.

More info here:

[Problems trying to get USB Debugging working on Windows 7 (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207709/problems-trying-to-get-usb-debugging-working-on-windows-7-android)